# Array type expected : found class name

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Basically what I want is to display the response that i got to my textview `flagName` I have created the model class from my json object but I'm currently having an error. Can anyone point out to me why I'm having this error that says `array required, but class name found` AND `cannot find symbol variable length` I'm not sure if I'm setting it correctly though and why does it need to be array when my json is in json objects. Help me fix this I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Kindly share the `FlagReportStamped` class

Comment: @SunilChakravarthy Kindly check the edited post above.

Comment: As you can see getFlagReport returns FlagReport not FlagReport[]. In your code you are assuming it’s an array and getting its length.

Comment: i request you to submit your api json response.

Comment: @CodeInsideCofee i've serialized them into model class  just kindly check it above.

Comment: update your json response

Comment: @ArulMani i have edited my post. kindly check above post.

Comment: You want to put all data inside flag_report {} into Spannable is this correct?

Comment: yes that will also set their color accordingly just like the previous code that i have. @ArulMani

Comment: first, you cant access POJO object variable via ```[]``` i.e walking_front, rotating_right .. etc

Comment: @ArulMani okay so how do i access it then?

Answer (score 0):

Your response is of type `FlagReportStamped`. `response.body()` returns `FlagReportStamped`.

When you say `response.body().getFlagReport()`, you get `FlagReport` instance.

In your code, you are expecting `FlagReport[]`. For that reason, it says `array required, but class name found` AND `cannot find symbol variable length`

Based on `FlagReport` class shared,

1. You need to first remove the `for` loop
2. Use `getFlagReport()` instead of `getFlagReport[i]`
3. Fix other bugs related to `FlagReport`. For example, setting `ForegroundColorSpan`

Comment: what changes am I suppose to do?

Comment: I need to know your `FlagReport` class. Updated your question with that

Comment: i have added the `FlagReport` class, kindly check above.

Comment: updated my answer. however, there are bugs in your code. setting `ForegroundColorSpan` has bug in it. you should get right value from `FlagReport` and use it

Comment: Since your original question is answered, can you mark and close?